# How to change height of images in Carousal?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

```
                     <Carousel>  

                     <Carousel.Item style={{'height':"300px"}} >  

                     <img style={{'height':"300px"}}  

                     className="d-inline-block w-100 h-100  "  
                     src={'https://media3.giphy.com/media/3oKHWoHCr4VtVI6H0A/giphy.gif'}    />  
                       <Carousel.Caption>  


                             </Carousel.Caption>  

                             </Carousel.Item  >  

                             <Carousel.Item style={{'height':"300px "}}>  

                                <img style={{'height':"300px"}}  

                                 className="d-block w-100"  

                                 src={'https://dumynlq1n57zm.cloudfront.net/article/167/e91b583-phpCrKL3N.gif'}    />  

                                   <Carousel.Caption>
```

### No matter whichever css styling  I change images size wont change please help me with that.

---

What should be changed please suggest

---

Cards.css

```
.carousel {
  width:110%;
  height:600px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: try using style={{height:" 300px"}} instead of style={{'height':"300px"}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the proportion, you should use :

```
.carousel {
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
}
```

If the image does not appear, show your code.

Comment: Images are rendering but their sizes are not changing .This code just changes the carousel height and width.

Comment: Here is the code :- https://codepen.io/samarth0807/pen/wvobKqq

Comment: You can't use style on carousel element. I think there is a problem on your div around the <Carousel> .